# Powershell script duplicate existing files inside destination folder while copying files

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

In my following Powershell script I am unzipping a zipped folder, moving another folder (from a different path) into the path of this unzipped folder. Finally, zip back the unzipped folder and delete any temporary paths that I have created during this process. It is copying folder across successfully but to my surprise, the existing files inside the unzipped folder are getting duplicated.

Would please someone tell me what I am doing wrong here?

```
if(Test-Path $Env:BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY/MyProject/WEB/dist)
{
    if(Test-Path $Env:BUILD_ArtifactStagingDirectory\MyProject.API.zip)
    {
        Expand-Archive -Path $Env:BUILD_ARTIFACTSTAGINGDIRECTORY\MyProject.API.zip -DestinationPath $Env:BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY\MyProject\API\temp -Force
        Write-Host "MyProject.API.zip folder unzipped successfully!"

        New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $Env:BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY\MyProject\WEB\temp1
        Write-Host "A temporary folder 'temp1' inside Web project sources directory created."

        New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $Env:BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY\MyProject\WEB\temp1\temp2
        Write-Host "A temporary folder 'temp2' inside temp1 created."

        Copy-Item $Env:BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY\MyProject\WEB\dist\* -Destination $Env:BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY\MyProject\WEB\temp1\temp2 -Recurse
        Write-Host "Web project dist folder content copied to the temp temp2 folder"

        Copy-Item -Path $Env:BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY\MyProject\WEB\temp1\* -Destination $(Get-ChildItem -Path $Env:BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY\MyProject\API\temp -Directory -Recurse | ? {$_.Basename -eq 'MyDestinationFolder'} | % { $_.FullName}) -Recurse -Force
        Write-Host "temp2 folder and its content copied to the 'MyDestinationFolder' folder of the unzipped folder."

        if(Test-Path $Env:BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY\MyProject\WEB\temp1)
        {
            Remove-Item -Recurse -Force $Env:BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY\MyProject\WEB\temp1
            Write-Host "Temporary temp1 folder deleted."
        }
        Compress-Archive -Path $Env:BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY\MyProject\API\temp\* -Update -DestinationPath $Env:BUILD_ARTIFACTSTAGINGDIRECTORY\MyProject.API.zip
        Write-Host "Unzipped folder is zipped back."

        Remove-Item -Recurse -Force $Env:BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY\MyProject\API\temp
        Write-Host "Temporary unzipped folder deleted."
    }
}
```

Comment: So essentially, you need to extract a .zip, copy a file into the extracted directory, then zip it back up again?

Comment: That's true @Matt

Comment: Are you just trying to add one file into the zip, or many files?

Comment: Many files and folders.

Answer (score 0):

It's this line:

```
Compress-Archive -Path $Env:BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY\MyProject\API\temp\* -Update -DestinationPath $Env:BUILD_ARTIFACTSTAGINGDIRECTORY\MyProject.API.zip
```

You're telling it to update the existing zip file, so it adds items to the zip file - including the content that you added to \API\temp here:

```
Copy-Item -Path $Env:BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY\MyProject\WEB\temp1\* -Destination $(Get-ChildItem -Path $Env:BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY\MyProject\API\temp -Directory -Recurse | ? {$_.Basename -eq 'MyDestinationFolder'} | % { $_.FullName}) -Recurse -Force
```

Basically, create a new zip file or remove the `-update` from your `compress-archive` cmdlet. Or you could check to see if the file exists, and if it doesn't - zip it up. Use the `Test-Path` cmdlet to check it.

Comment: Removing -Update parameter gives the error of either to use -Update to update the existing archive or -Force to replace existing. I have tried -Force but the optimal compression level causing a trouble in my devops release pipeline where 'IIS Web App Deploy' task can't load the zip folder.

Comment: How about making a new zip file, uploading the zip to an Azure Artifact and consuming it in your IIS Web App Deploy task?

Comment: New zip folder is coming out same as -Force parameter. Already have tried that. It will be good to find out the compression type used by the 'Build Solution' task to create the build artifact.

Answer (score 0):

So you don't need to unpack the `MyProject.API.zip`, then add files to it, then repack it, in order to inject files into it... You can add "loose" files into an existing `.zip` file as it stands.

This is how I tested it: (*you should be able to follow these steps in order to achieve what you are trying to accomplish, I used these steps since they are easier to follow*):

- Created a directory and file at `C:\testing\toAdd\FileToAdd.txt` (this simulates the files I
  want to inject)
- Created a directory and Zip file at `C:\testing\zip\Zip.zip` (this simulates where my .zip file lives)
- There are 2 files in the `Zip.zip` file:
- 1. `New Text Document 1.txt`
- 2. `New Text Document 2.txt`

All I had to do was run the following command to "inject" `FileToAdd.txt` into `Zip.zip`:

```
Compress-Archive -Path C:\testing\toAdd\* -DestinationPath C:\testing\zip\Zip.zip -Update
```

*Screenshots below:*

---

**File To Add Path**

[image: File To Add Path]

---

**Destination ZIP File Path and Contents:**

[image: Destination ZIP File Path and Contents]

---

**Contents Of `Zip.zip` After Running Command Listed Above:**

[image: After Running Command Listed Above]

---

Hope this helps!

Comment: that's what I'm already doing and it is creating the duplicate of all the existing files inside MyDestinationFolder. However, Any file or folder copied over from
 
`Copy-Item -Path $Env:BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY\MyProject\WEB\temp1\*` 

location is not duplicated.

Comment: But that's not what you're doing. You're clearly unpacking the zip file first. You don't need to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is something else you can try.. I wrote this function for you..

[Link to function can be found here.](https://gist.github.com/oze4/bb075e845070f322baccc041b3c3df91)

```
function Add-ToZipFile {

    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [ValidateScript({
                    [System.IO.File]::Exists($_) -and [System.IO.FileInfo]::new($_).Extension -eq ".zip"

                    # YOU MUST SUPPLY AN EXISTING ZIP FILE PATH!!!
        })]
        [string]$ZipFilePath,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
        [string[]]$FilesToAdd,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
        [string[]]$FoldersToAdd
    )

    try {

        foreach($file in $FilesToAdd){
            if(Test-Path -Path $file -PathType Leaf) {
                Compress-Archive -Path $file -DestinationPath $ZipFilePath -Update
            } else {
                Write-Host "Unable to locate file: $($file) - Please make sure this file exists!" -f Red
            }
        }

        foreach($folder in $FoldersToAdd){
            if(Test-Path -Path $folder -PathType Container){
                $f = $folder.TrimEnd("\")
                $f = $f.TrimEnd("/")
                Compress-Archive -Path "$($f)" -DestinationPath $ZipFilePath -Update                             
            } else {
                Write-Host "Unable to locate folder: $($folder) - Please make sure this folder exists!" -f Red
            }
        }
    } catch {
        Write-Error "Something went wrong! Error: `r`n$($_)"    
    }
}
```

***Here is how to use it:***

```
# MUST BE AN ARRAY OF STRINGS
# EVEN IF YOU HAVE A SINGLE PATH TO ADD, SURROUND IT IN '@( )' IN ORDER TO MAKE IT AN ARRAY
$files = @("C:\testing\SecondFileToAdd.txt")

# MUST BE AN ARRAY OF STRINGS 
$folders = @("C:\testing\toAdd", "C:\testing\anotherToAdd") 

# PATH TO ZIP FILE
$myZipPath = "C:\testing\zip\Zip.zip"

Add-ToZipFile -ZipFilePath $myZipPath -FilesToAdd $files -FoldersToAdd $folders
```

Please let me know if this doesn't work (although, in my testing it worked just fine)..

Comment: Thanks @Matt. I have changed my build pipeline. Started using Archive task to generate zip manually rather the auto generated by the build.